# Google Cloud Vision not recognizing Arabic Characters

Tags: google-cloud-vision

Hi I am trying Google Cloud Vision , to detect character and words in Arabic language from image. But when i try it gives me result in matching them with english:

Request code is as below:

```
{
  "requests": [
{
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "TEXT_DETECTION"
    }
  ],
  "image": {
    "source": {
      "imageUri": "gs://dummy/noon-1.png"
    }
  },
  "imageContext": {
    "languageHints": [
      "ar"
    ]
  }
}
]
}
```

Comment: for a word containing multiple character it is detecting fine but for single caracters it is giving back result for english instead of Arabic

Answer (score 0):

The Vision API service use **machine learning models** that are being trained constantly in order to improve the results quality; however, sometimes they get the characters wrong or even they don't recognize the characters themselves

Based on this, I suggest you take a look on the [Supported Images](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/supported-files) document where you can find some `file format` and `image sizing` recommendations that may help you to improve your results accuracy, as well use the **Send Feedback** button, located at the lower left and upper right corners of the [Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/) public documentation, or use the [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests) tool in order to [raise a Vision API request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187174&template=0) and notify to Google about this behavior.